# What's the most intuitive way to decide if interaction exists between 2 categorical variables in regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, interaction

To discern interaction between categorical and numerical variable, one can look at the slope change. What's an intuitive visual way to detect or deny interaction between categorical variables?

Besides graphical methods, I've also found using trees techniques to identify interaction terms, such as in randomforestSRC package, but I couldn't find info on how to read the output of such.

Any advice?

Comment: By "numerical" variable, do you mean a variable that is continuous?

Comment: I'd start by plotting means at each level of your categorical variable.  If you see large changes in the mean for different levels of your categorical variable, you probably have some interaction going on.  You could carry this out a bit more formally with an ANOVA if your data meets the ANOVA assumptions.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. numerical could mean discrete numbers too, such as 1,2,3, ..., 20

Comment: Package sjPlot has nice plots of interactions: http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/articles/plot_interactions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the combinations of the categorical and numerical variable,  then plot the relationship with the dependent variable, would be able to see the influence on the dependent variable.

If categorical variables were *C* and numerical were *N*, then you could have:

```
C1N1, C1N2, C1N3, C2N1, C2N2, C3N3...
```

and so forth. If they are highly correlated, then it is possible there is interaction there, of course be wary if one factor was already strongly correlated to begin with.

To do it non-visually, could take the step above and look at coefficient strength of the interaction terms, this could be done by normalizing the values for the categorical, numerical and interaction variables and then looking at the correlations.

Comment: could you provide a bit more detail of why this may be a good idea? I appreciate that due to your reputation you can't leave this as a comment, but if you want to answer it is necessary to put more detail. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance on answering questions. A good answer can get your reputation climbing quickly.